# How to debug and step into a COM object

Tags: c#, debugging, asp-classic, com

I have a classic ASP website running on IIS. The site uses some COM objects (via VBScript CreateObject), which actually are .DLL's written in C#. So the question is how can I debug the C# code in Visual Studio 2017?

I tried to attach to a process w3wp.exe, but it does not show any DLL's, just script code:
[image]

My PDB files are placed in the same folder as the DLL's and I also unchecked "Just my code", but nothing helps. Since no dlls loaded, no symbols loaded my breakpoints do not hit

Comment: Have you tried making sure when attaching to the w3wp.exe you also specify to attached to the managed code version your C# DLL is using? Use the `Select` option in the `Attach to Process` window next to `Attach to` to select what code debuggers to attach to the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are attaching the debugger to a Classic ASP Web Application you need to make sure that you tell it that you want to debug managed code as well.

1. In the `Attach to Process` window before selecting the process to attach to, locate the `Select...` option to the right of the `Attach to:` label;

   [image: Attach to Process Window]

   This will open the `Select Code Type` window where you can select the code type debuggers to attach.
2. Select multiple code types from those listed, specifically the `Managed` version of .Net that fits the compilation of the .Net COM DLL you wish to debug.

   [image: Select Code Type Window]
3. Attach to the process as normal.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried attaching the `w3wp.exe` in your `C# application`? you can open that `C# application` and make sure that outout of that application is the `DLL` which is referenced there and put breakpoint on the method which you want to debug, while attaching the `debugger`, the `output window` itself can tell you whether the right `symbols` are loaded or not, if it says `symbols` are loaded then `breakpoint` will  hit.

Give it a try it should work as i've faced this previously.